# How to center a wx.BusyInfo() - wxpython?

Tags: python, wxpython, wxwidgets

Looking at the API there doesn't seem to be a way to center a wx.BusyInfo message to the center of the screen like with other pop  up modals by using Center().

Is there a way to center wx.BusyInfo()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not with wx.BusyInfo, as far as I know (although it should be already centered by default... have you tried *not* giving a parent window to the wx.BusyInfo?).

Alternatively, you may want to try wx.lib.agw.PyBusyInfo instead: if it doesn't do exactly what you need, you can always hack it to suit your needs (it's pure Python).

Hope this helps.

Andrea.

Answer (score 0):

Little late: but you can center a busyInfo window by specifying a parent. It will center on the parent, otherwise it will center on the screen.